# laravel 5.4 can't install

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Upgrading laravel to 5.4 from 5.3.

I was changed `composer.json`, when I run composer update , i got errors.

composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```

errors:

```
git:(upgrade-5.4) ✗ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.2.2
    - Installation request for mpociot/laravel-test-factory-helper ^0.3.1 -> satisfiable by mpociot/laravel-test-factory-helper[0.3.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.2.1
    - laravel/framework v5.4.6 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.0 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.1 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.2 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.3 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.4 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - laravel/framework v5.4.5 requires symfony/console ~3.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.2.0|install symfony/console v3.2.1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.2, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6].
```

Comment: delete your vendor folder and run `composer install`

Comment: Thanks. Have tried, but didn't work for me.

Comment: try reset your changes of composer.json and execute command `composer require "laravel/framework:5.4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `mpociot/laravel-test-factory-helper` from your (dev-?) dependencies or update it to a version that supports Laravel 5.4